# Why is my Android phone unable to detect some wireless access points?

Tags: wi-fi

I created an unsecured ad-hoc network from my Mac machine and scanned for networks using my LG Optimus 3D, tried Samsung Galaxy Pop also. But unfortunately both the phone doesn't seem to pick up the private access point I have created.

But the network is detectable by other laptops and phones (except Android).

I need this connection to happen via Wi-Fi, but seems I am not able to get out of this problem. I tried Wi-Fi tether to do this the other way round, but it seems to be buggy. The tether works for some time but fails some other time (pretty unstable).

Is there any stable solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

## If it is an Ad-hoc network

[Vanilla Android does not support Ad-hoc Wi-Fi networks.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82) But there is a patch for the wpa_supplicant, that allows you to connect to Ad-hoc networks *(root required)*:

- http://www.xda-developers.com/android/android-ad-hoc-wireless-network-support/
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=754961
- http://szym.net/2010/12/adhoc-wifi-in-android/
- http://szym.net/2010/12/prospects-of-ad-hoc-wifi-in-android/

**But [Android 4.0 supports](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/index.html) [Wi-Fi Direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct), which can be seen as a more enhanced version of the Ad-hoc protocol.**

## If you have an soft-AP

This sounds like you **AP is transmitting on a channel that is not avaiable on your Android phones.** Try setting the Wi-Fi channel to something < 12 e.g. 5.

Comment: The network is ad-hoc. I heard by default android phones don't support ad-hoc. Is there any way to do it in my LG Optimus 3d?

Comment: @JuliusCanute That important piece of information was missing, maybe you should edit your question: There are no "Access Points" in ad-hoc networks. :) I have updated my answer.

Comment: I think i have corrected now. My phones wpa_supplicant version is v0.6.10. Is it ok if I apply the path which seems to be v0.5.11?

Comment: Also I tried wpa_supplicant version 0.6.10 from the following link:http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/19556-howto-ad-hoc-wireless-connections/ but it didn't work. I am getting an error stating "Unable to scan for networks" Wherein none of the access points are detected.